# Why am I getting this message " Further output of NIntegrate::inumri will be suppressed during this calculation."

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, warning-messages

My code is:

```
p = 0.01; 
m = -0.5*Log[2.9]; 
s = Sqrt[Log[2.9]]; 
r = 0.5; 
tailF[x_] := 1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (Log[x] - m)/s] 
t = Quantile[LogNormalDistribution[m, s], p] 
g == 
  N[(Integrate[(tailF[y]/(1 - p))^(r), {y, t, Infinity}] - 
       Integrate[tailF[y]/(1 - p), {y, t, Infinity}]) / 
    (Integrate[ tailF[y]/(1 - p), {y, t, Infinity}])] 
v1 == 
  -r ΝIntegrate[((tailF[x]/(1 - p))^r) Log[tailF[x]/(1 - p)], {x, t, Infinity}]
```

> NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand 1.00504 (1-1/2 Erfc[-0.484567 (0.532355 +Log[<<1>>])])^0.5 Log[1.0101 (1-1/2 Erfc[-0.484567 Plus[<<2>>]])] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.0532481,5.23043*10^7}}
>
> General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumri will be suppressed during this calculation.

Can you please help why I am getting this message?

Comment: NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand 1.00504 (1-1/2 Erfc[-0.484567 (0.532355 +Log[<<1>>])])^0.5 Log[1.0101 (1-1/2 Erfc[-0.484567 Plus[<<2>>]])] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.0532481,5.23043*10^7}}.

Comment: Please provide the code that generates the message.

Comment: v1 == -0.5 ΝIntegrate[
   1.00504 (1 - 1/2 Erfc[-0.685282 (0.532355 + Log[x])])^0.5 Log[
     1.0101 (1 - 1/2 Erfc[-0.685282 (0.532355 + Log[x])])], {x, 
    0.0532481, \[Infinity]}] my question is how i can computing this result

Comment: Because more than 3 messages of the form `NIntegrate::inumri` were thrown. That means you are doing something wrong quite often. I guess something bad is going on with your integrand.

Comment: you have right!! thank you!

Comment: = 0; r = 0.5;
k = 3.22222; a = 4.22222;tailF[x_] := k^a/(x + k)^a;VaR[p_] := k*(1 - p)^{-1/a} - k;g1 = Module[{int1, int2}, int1 = NIntegrate[tailF[y]/(1 - p), {y, VaR[p], Infinity}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 20];int2 = NIntegrate[(tailF[y]/(1 - p))^(r), {y, t, \[Infinity]}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 20];
  (int2 - int1)/int1]
v = Module[{int3, int4}, 
  int3 = -r*
    NIntegrate[((tailF[y]/(1 - p))^r)*Log[tailF[y]/(1 - p)], {y, 
      VaR[p], Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
  int4 = NIntegrate[(tailF[y]/(1 - p))^r, {y, VaR[p], Infinity}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20];
  int3/int4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit

Your numeric problems are induced because you are using machine precision arithmetic. The fix is to define the parameters as exact quantities and do the computations with Mathematica's arbitrary precision arithmetic.

You also have some bad syntax in your code, I will correct those errors in presentation of the making of the computation with  arbitrary precision arithmetic.

My solution uses exactly the same approach as Bob Hanlon's, but I also worked out a computation for `g`. I omit repeating Bob's work, but give the code for computing `g`.

```
p = 1/100;
q = 29/10;
m = -Log[q]/2;
s = Sqrt[Log[q]];
r = 1/2;

tailF[x_] := 1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (Log[x] - m)/s]

t = N[Quantile[LogNormalDistribution[m, s], p], 20]
```

> 0.053248094037394870890`

```
g =
  Module[{int1, int2},
    int1 = NIntegrate[tailF[y]/(1 - p), {y, t, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
    int2 = NIntegrate[(tailF[y]/(1 - p))^(r), {y, t, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
    (int2 - int1)/int1]
```

> `2.0043916495150882408`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have a very short time learning this program. In the future I will have more questions!!! :) You where very helpful!!

Comment: v == Module[{int3, int4}, 
  int3 = -r*
    NIntegrate[((tailF[y]/(1 - p))^r)*Log[tailF[y]/(1 - p)], {y, t, 
      Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
  int4 = NIntegrate[(tailF[y]/(1 - p))^r, {y, t, Infinity}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20];
  int3/int4]... i bult this one with the some 
thought but it give False for p=0!

Comment: @BobHanlon. I have corrected the error.

Comment: @PolixeniVliora. Why are you using `==` rather than `=`?  With `p =0`. the righthand side gives `1.8913582973597114875`. Why do expect testing for equality to `v`, which is what you are doing, would give `True`, the only other value your expression could have.

Comment: yes i found it after i sent the message.  Can i ask you something else..? When i get another distribution its happened numerical problem and the program doesnt compute the intervals..

Comment: @PolixeniVliora. I don't understand your new question, You don't give enough details. Also, it is not good practice to ask a new question in a comment to an answer of a previous question. You should post you new problem in a new question.

Comment: p = 0; r = 0.5;
k = 3.22222; a = 4.22222;
tailF[x_] := k^a/(x + k)^a
VaR[p_] := k*(1 - p)^{-1/a} -k;g1 = Module[{int1, int2}, 
  int1 = NIntegrate[tailF[y]/(1 - p), {y, VaR[p], Infinity}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20];int2 = NIntegrate[(tailF[y]/(1 - p))^(r), {y, t, \[Infinity]}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 20];(int2 - int1)/int1]
v = Module[{int3, int4}, 
  int3 = -r*
    NIntegrate[((tailF[y]/(1 - p))^r)*Log[tailF[y]/(1 - p)], {y, 
      VaR[p], Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
  int4 = NIntegrate[(tailF[y]/(1 - p))^r, {y, VaR[p], Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
  int3/int4]

Comment: hello ,
something happened when the message was loaded. its the same functions and the same problem in another distribution..

Comment: @PolixeniVliora. Really, and I'm serious, don't dump the code of a  new question into a comment. Ask a new question.

Comment: @PolixeniVliora, Well, one very bad you have done is go back to expressing parameters as machine reals. That will always destroy a high precision computation. You must express them as exact numbers or high precision number with precision greater or equal to the working precision

Comment: i'm blogging for the first time i don't know how it works. sorry i will ask a new question about  my query!

Answer (score 2):

Use exact constants so that the numerical integration can be done with a specified level of precision.

```
p = 1/100; 
m = -1/2*Log[29/10]; 
s = Sqrt[Log[29/10]]; 
r = 1/2;

tailF[x_] := 1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (Log[x] - m)/s] 

t = Quantile[LogNormalDistribution[m, s], p];

v1 = -r*NIntegrate[((tailF[x]/(1 - p))^r)*Log[tailF[x]/(1 - p)], 
    {x, t, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* 5.4205112147940705531 *)
```

**EDIT:** regarding the comment,

```
a = NIntegrate[(tailF[x]/(1 - p))^r, {x, t, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* 2.8735704898654341928 *)

v1/a

(* 1.8863331294329607670 *)
```

Comment: so you suggest me to calculate a finite number, ok thank you. But if i want this one v1 = -r*NIntegrate[((tailF[x]/(1 - p))^r)*Log[tailF[x]/(1 - p)], {x, 
       t, Infinity}]/(Integrate[(tailF[x]/(1 - p))^r, {x, t, 
        Infinity}), WorkingPrecision -> 20]??? 
i'm grateful for helping me!!